# Function to return OpenGL #define error name from its hexadecimal value

Tags: c++, opengl

I have been learning about OpenGL recently, and was searching information about error handling. I learned to use `glGetError` to set the error flag and created a function that prints its hexadecimal value. The relevant C++ code looks like this:

```
GLClearError();
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_INT, nullptr);
GLCheckError();
```

with GL_INT written on purpose. `GLClearError()` just clears the error flag and `GlCheckError()` prints the errors produced by `glDrawElements`.

I get `500` as an output. I know I can go (in my case, as I use GLEW) to *glew.h* and search for the error with this number. In this case, the error is `GL_INVALID_ENUM`. It's a compiler definition; my question then is the following: is it possible to create in C++ a function that returns the definition name by entering its value? I use C++ 11, OpenGL 4.6 and GLEW 2.1, if that changes anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to create in C++ a function that returns the definition name by entering its value?

Yes, it is.

Unless someone has done it already, you'll have to do it in your application code.

E.g.

```
enum MyEnum { ENUM_VALUE_1, ENUM_VALUE_2, ENUM_VALUE_3, ... };

std::string getEnumName(MyEnum e)
{
   static std::map<MyEnum, std::string> nameMap =
   {
      {ENUM_VALUE_1, "ENUM_VALUE_1"},
      {ENUM_VALUE_2, "ENUM_VALUE_2"},
      {ENUM_VALUE_3, "ENUM_VALUE_3"},
      ...
   };

   return nameMap[e];
}
```

Comment: Little bit of [macro magic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49236965/44729) can save you some typing.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the library provides, or you yourself write, a function to translate the numeric error to a string representation, then it's not possible.

There is no way to, at run time, translate the value of a macro (`#define`) into the name of the macro.

But it's perfectly possible to write a function that takes an error code, looks it up in a table and returns some string (that you write) for each error.